# Free Fall Motion in Physics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A man in a close elevator with no floor indicator,does not know whether the elevator is stationary, moving upward or moving downward at a constant velocity. To try to find out, the person drops a coin from a height of 2 m and times its fall with a stopwatch. If he got a record of 3/4 of the time he expect, how far does the elevator travel the moment he drop coin till it reach the floor? Is it moving upward or downward.

Comment: Why did he expect different results than what he gets? He should learn to make better expectations. Or if his meter sticks and/or clocks are defective he should get better ones or learn to compensate.

Comment: Hi Jaydel and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Is this a homework question?   I ask that cause the way question's written is flawed.   Constant velocity and 3/4 time expected wouldn't happen.   With constant velocity you can't tell that the elevator is moving by the coin test.   The coin test can detect changes in velocity but not constant velocity.

Answer (score 1):

The person's expectation of arriving at a different value is incorrect theoretically. The coin AND the person are both inside an inertial frame and the coin will travel the height of the elevator in the same period of time whether its stationary or moving with constant velocity.So, this experiment is not a valid test for the the state of the motion. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The coin and the person are both moving with the elevator at a constant speed ((or are at rest with the elevator). That does not change the time it takes to hit the floor. While going down, the coin already has a downward speed same as that of elevator. While going up, it already has an upward speed same as that of elevator. While at rest, it has same speed as that of elevator which is 0. So, in all three cases, the time taken will be same.